# Countable set in a Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and let $(e_k)$ be a total orthonormal sequence in $H$. We consider the set $A$ of all linear combinations $$\gamma_1^{(n)}e_1+\cdots+\gamma_n^{(n)}e_n\qquad n=1,2,\dots$$
where $\gamma_k^{(n)}=a_k^{(n)}+ib_k^{(n)}$ and $a_k^{(n)}$ and $b_k^{(n)}$ are rational.

I have to prove that $A$ is countable. I thought about this application:

$$f\colon A\to\mathbb{Q}\times\cdots\times \mathbb{Q}\quad(n-\text{times})$$ defined as $$\gamma_1^{(n)}e_1+\cdots+\gamma_n^{(n)}e_n\mapsto(\gamma_1^{(n)},\dots, \gamma_2^{(n)}).$$ Clearly this application is bijective, and then since $\mathbb{Q}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Q}$ ($n$-times) is countable we can conclude that $A$ is countable.

It's correct?

Comment: The $\gamma_k^{(n)}$ are not rationals themselves but you are not far off at all, right idea except you want to use the $a$s and $b$s in your map.